# Android: original firmware identification strings for different models

Tags: android, model, firmware, handset

Is there anywhere a summary of **Build.MODEL** strings for different Android handset models? Something like:

- "Hero" - HTC Hero
- "ERA G2 Touch" - branded HTC Hero
- "T-Mobile myTouch 3G" - branded HTC Magic
- "GT-I5700" - Samsung Galaxy
- ... and so on

I'm curious what is the percent of rooted devices among my app users, but sometimes is hard to tell which device is which (and yes, I know rooted firmware can mimic vanilla one, it just usually doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [list of android devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices) in Wikipedia contains such data

Comment: I don't see where it has Build.MODEL.